# How to fix code for octagon of asterisk in python?

Tags: python

The problem is my code runs but that it does not create an octagon shape. The shape the stars make is similar to an octagon but I need code that creates a regular shaped octagon and I am confused on what's wrong with the code.

```
length = int(input("What is the length of one side? "))
for i in range(length):
    print(' ' * (length - i-1) + '*' * (length + i*2))
for i in range(length-1):
    print('*' * ((length * 2)))
for i in range(length):
    print(' ' * (i+1) + '*' * ((length-i)*2))
```

No error messages but code does not produce desired outcome of an octagon shape when user inputs a number.

Comment: Hi, the code that was edited by wjandrea is still incorrect. Can someone still help me. The edited code still does not produce a perfect octagon shape and produces an octagon shape that is unbalanced and not centralized. Can someone please perfect this code.

Comment: I didn't edit your code at all, just fixed the formatting

Comment: No, the formatting was good but for some reason the code will not run a regular octagon shape but is off a little bit and is not straight

Comment: No, the formatting was wrong. It was all on one line. I've just fixed it again for you though. Again, I didn't edit your code at all.

Comment: If you're having trouble seeing how the formatting appeared, check out [revision 1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/58252938/1)

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
length = int(input("What is the length of one side? ")) 
for i in range(length - 1): 
  print(' ' * (length - i-1) + '*' * (length + i*2)) 
for i in range(length): 
  print('*' * ((length + 2 * (length - 1))))
for i in range(length - 2, -1, -1): 
  print(' ' * (length - i-1) + '*' * (length + i*2))
```

The formula for the second step was wrong, and for the last section you can reuse the logic for the first section but running it backwards, hope this help you :)

**Edit**
I realized that the count of the vertical sides doesn't match with the length, so this would be the correction for that code, but for the case where the length is 1 it displays a single point, and if you think about it it may have sense to be like that because for this apparent solution

*

***

*

There's no side for the diagonals, so I think that this edited version is better, and a single asterisk for case 1 makes sense.

Comment: thanks, seems to have solved my problem but when input is 1 it produces 2 stars when it is only suppose to produce 1. Other than that, this really helped.